# Donation Pages Automatically Redirect

Tags: civicontribute

## Issue

Links to donation pages result in automatic redirects to the home page for users other than administrators. Base page loads correctly. ACL is configured to allow contributions from all types of users (anonymous included).

## Configuration

WordPress Version: 5.5.1
PHP Version: 7.3.19
MySQL Version: 5.5.5
Server Software: nginx/1.17.6
Your User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15
Session Save Path:
Session Save Path Exists: No
Session Save Path Writeable: No
Session Max Lifetime: 1440
WP Multisite Mode: No
WP Memory Limit: 40M

Currently Active Theme: Divi: 4.6.3

## Wordpress Plugins

Caldera Forms: 1.9.2 Active
Caldera Forms Stripe: 1.4.7 Active
Caldera Forms Style Customizer (CFSC) for Divi & Extra: 1.0.3 Active
Caldera Forms Users: 1.3.10 Active
CalderaWP License Manager: 1.2.10 Active
CF CiviCRM: 1.0.5 Active
CiviCRM: 5.29.1 Active
Mail Templates For Caldera Forms: 1.0.4 Active
Query Monitor: 3.6.4 Not Active
Really Simple SSL: 3.3.5 Active
WP Mail SMTP: 2.4.0 Active

## CiviCRM Extensions

Access Control by Financial Type for Reports
(biz.jmaconsulting.financialaclreport)  Enabled 1.1
CiviMobileAPI
(com.agiliway.civimobileapi)    Enabled 5.3.0
Stripe Payment Processor
(com.drastikbydesign.stripe)    Enabled 6.4.2
iATS Payments
(com.iatspayments.civicrm)  Enabled 1.7.2
Event ICS
(eventics)  Enabled 1.0
Firewall
(firewall)  Enabled 1.1
CSS/JS minifier for AssetBuilder
(minifier)  Enabled 1.0
MJWShared
(mjwshared) Enabled 0.8.1
FlexMailer
(org.civicrm.flexmailer)    Enabled 1.1.1
Sweet Alert
(sweetalert)    Enabled 1.3
Mosaico
(uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico)  Enabled 2.5.1597918155

Comment: Garrett welcome to CiviCRM stackexchange. Do you see any error in CiviCRM config log?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the extension **Access Control by Financial Type for Reports** that means you have [Access Control by Financial Type](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#financial-type-permissions) enabled. You have to set additional permissions when this is enabled.

> You must grant the add and view permission for each financial type to
> the anonymous user role for visitors to be able to access your contribution pages.

I submitted this [PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/pull/460) to the docs as I had encountered this issue as well.